# Auxilio com predição de variáveis com machine learning e classes não balanceadas no R(caret)

Tags: r, machine-learning

Eu estou aprendendo técnicas de machine learning para predizer valores de tamanho de folhas (numéricos) a partir de múltiplos preditores (numéricos). No entanto, os tamanhos de folha são condicionados a forma de vida, (árvores ou gramas), as quais não são balanceadas. No momento, eu estou criando a separação dos dados usando os valores "tamanho de folha" (a váriavel que eu quero predizer) e gerando modelos separados para cada classe. A minha dúvida é: eu preciso criar modelos separados para cada classe, ou existe alguma opção que eu consiga separar os dados em treinamento e teste nas classes existentes e gerar um único no modelo que gere a predição dos tamanhos de folha, levando em consideração a classe (forma_vida) (e se alguém tiver uma dica ~para alguém que nunca lidou com ml antes~ de como lidar com o fato delas não serem balanceadas).

```
library(caret)
# Parte dos dados
> dput(head(df))
structure(list(tam_folha = c(4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L), forma_vida = structure(c(1L,2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("arvore", "grama"), class = "factor"), 
X1036 = c(0.349, 0.342, 0.383, 0.325, 0.309), X1037 = c(0.349, 
0.342, 0.383, 0.325, 0.309), X1038 = c(0.349, 0.342, 0.383, 
0.325, 0.309), X1039 = c(0.349, 0.342, 0.383, 0.325, 0.309
), X1040 = c(0.349, 0.342, 0.383, 0.325, 0.31), X1041 = c(0.349, 
0.342, 0.383, 0.326, 0.31)), .Names = c("X", "Y", "X1036","X1037", "X1038", "X1039", "X1040", "X1041"), row.names = c(NA,5L), class = "data.frame")

#Filtrando por classes
arvores = df %>% dplyr::filter(forma_vida=="arvore")

# Data partition
index <- createDataPartition(arvores$tam_folha, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
train_data <- arvores[index, ]
test_data  <- arvores[-index, ]

controle = trainControl(method ="cv",number= 10, repeat=5, selectionFunction = "oneSE")
mod1 <- train(tam_folha ~ ., data = train_data,
method = "pls",
metric = "RMSE",
tuneLength = 4,
trControl = controle)

##repete para o fator::gramas
```

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente não tenho pontuação mínima para realizar comentários, então...

Pelo que entendi o objetivo é apenas predizer o tamanho de uma folha, que pode ser de uma árvore ou uma grama, correto?

Se sim, deve-se construir um modelo de regressão para cada tipo de "planta", árvore ou grama. Ou seja, dois modelos devem ser criados.

A questão do des/balanceamento é rigorosa em métodos de classificação, que, aí sim, poderia-se pensar em balancear e predizer a qual planta determinada folha pertence, árvore ou grama?

Sugiro utilizar o [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) para dúvidas com este tipo de conteúdo.

Quanto a automatização da rotina, talvez utilizando um `for` com loop seja possível gerar os dois modelos automaticamente. E cuidado com a função `createDataPartition`, para não obter resultados "aleatórios". Use o `set.seed()`.